# How to change pi-chart to a Donut chart unsing html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How to change pi-chart to a Donut chart unsing html5 canvas. please check the below fiddle.I'am trying to chnage this pi-chart to donut chat.
http://jsfiddle.net/ya3ya6/yd3rzo42/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("pichart");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var lastend = 0;
var data = [40, 40, 20];
var myTotal = 0;
var myColor = ['#023858', '#0570B0', '#045A8D'];
var labels = ['40%', '40%', '20%'];
```

Comment: Beyond the rather simplistic: draw a white circle over the pie chart, what extra data do you want to show and where?

Comment: @A Haworth exactly same like fiddle

Comment: what is the most common method for charts. can i use google chats? is that easy for customization?

Comment: can any one provide a fiddle